# Ubuntu 14.04 configure switchable graphics Intel/AMD

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, graphics

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04 I lost the GUI. After rebooting the loading screen appears (that one with the logo and the dots that indicates the loading process). However, after that it appears the annoying black screen with the white underscore flashing. I've been trying many tutorials to configure the switchable graphics in a previous versions of Ubuntu, and at this moment, none of them works.

My two graphic cards are:

- Intel 3rd Gen Core Graphic Controller.
- AMD/ATI Chelsea Randeon HD 7730M

  Moreover, as a consequence of my attempts to solve the problem, it has been generated a lot of xorg.config files; such as; xorg.config.05072014 (note that is the date of each day) or xorg.config.fglrx0 from 0 up to 15. So I would like to know if I can safely remove some or all of them.

  So, I will appreciate any tip or advice for solving the graphical issue.